# I want to use 3d style emoji in html

Tags: javascript, 3d, emoji

`<h2 className="welcome">Welcome back </h2>`

This is displaying

[image]

I want to display like below image. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Emojis look different in different OSes. Maybe use images instead of emojis directly?

Comment: Do it just like you did it in this question, add the image using [`<img>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emojis look different on every platform
https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html